# Solrj: how to sort by a function

Tags: java, sorting, solr, solrj

I want to be able to sort my collection by a field called "severity" where its possible values are:

> - "fair"
> - "critical"
> - "warning"

Sorting by ascending severity should bring fair, warning, then critical.
Yet, the sort is done **alphabetically**.

How can I **implement a custom sort** through Solr's client for Java, Solrj?

Answer (score 0):

how about creating a new field with int data type and have it as 0 for fair, 1 for warning and 2 for critical. Then you can sort on this field which is an int

Also, have a look at the documentation about sorting
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#sort

> Sorting can be done on the "score" of the document, or on any
>   multiValued="false" indexed="true" field provided that field is either
>   non-tokenized (ie: has no Analyzer) or uses an Analyzer that only
>   produces a single Term (ie: uses the KeywordTokenizer)
>
> The common situation for sorting on a field that you do want to be
>   tokenized for searching is to use a  to clone your field.
>   Sort on one, search on the other.

Hope this helps